# Does Windows remove files with invalid characters within name during disk repair?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, fdisk

I have some files on external HDD whose names contain '**:**'. These files work fine on Ubuntu but fail to open in Windows.

Recently I tried doing a diskcheck on my external HDD and it poped-up that it requires repair. Upon repairing a found.000 folder was created on the disk. I initially suspected that my HDD has bad sectors but closer inspection revealed that the files or directories with invalid characters were removed.

If someone can kindly confirm if this really happens in Windows or it is really bad sector.

Comment: It is hard to say, but it is very likely that windows did this because it could not handle files with a :.

Comment: Maybe some insight here>>>>>https://www.windowsfilerecovery.com/chkdsk/deleted-invalid-filename

Comment: Recover files>>>>https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-files-deleted-by-chkdsk.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here.

(1) If the file somehow has invalid characters in the name, and is in your Documents folder (not Windows or Program files), Windows Repair will likely keep it.

(2) If the file is somewhere else and the result of a bad sector,  the results may be unpredictable.

It seems likely best if you can back up whatever you can and then attempt to rebuild the disk , or if need be, replace the disk.